# Show that $\mathbb{S}^p\times\mathbb{E}^{q+1}\cong \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{S}^{p+q+1} : |x| \geq |y| \} $

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is Exercise 3 of Chapter 4.4 of Ronald Brown's *Topology and Groupoids*.

Let the points of $\mathbb{R}^{p+q+2}$ be denoted $(x, y)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^{p+1}, y\in\mathbb{R}^{q+1}$. Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ denote the $n$-dimensional unit sphere and $\mathbb{E}^n$ the $n$-dimensional (closed) unit ball.

Define subsets $A_+, A_-$ of $\mathbb{S}^{p+q+1}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{p+q+2}$ by:
$$A_+ := \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{S}^{p+q+1} : |x| \geq |y| \} $$
$$A_- := \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{S}^{p+q+1} : |x| \leq |y| \}$$

The question is to show that $A_+$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^p\times \mathbb{E}^{q+1}$ and $A_+\cap A_-$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^p\times\mathbb{S}^q$.

We have been shown earlier in the chapter that $\mathbb{E}^{p+1}\times\mathbb{E}^{q+1}\cong\mathbb{E}^{p+q+1}$ with this restricting to a homeomorphism of $(\mathbb{S}^p\times \mathbb{E}^{q+1})\cup (\mathbb{E}^{p+1}\times \mathbb{S}^{q})\cong \mathbb{S}^{p+q+1}$. This homeomorphism comes from the homeomorphism: $$\left[x\mapsto \frac{|x|}{\lVert x \rVert} x\right ]:\mathbb{E}^n\to[-1, 1]^n$$ where $\lVert (x_1, \dots, x_n) \rVert = \text{max }_{i=1}^n(|x_i|)$ and the fact that $ [-1, 1]^{p+1}\times[-1, 1]^{q+1} = [-1, 1]^{p+q+2}$.

Unfortunately, this map does not behave well with the subsets $A_+, A_-$ so somehow needs to be modified seemingly to get the right result. I have spent a very long time on this question, but cannot seem to make that final step to the answer.

Comment: $E^{q+1}$ is the *closed* unit ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A^+\to\mathbb{S}^p\times\mathbb{E}^{q+1},\quad(x,y)\mapsto\left(\frac x{\sqrt{1-|y|^2}},y\sqrt2\right)$$
and its restriction
$A^+\cap A_-\to\mathbb{S}^p\times\mathbb{S}^q$
are homeomorphisms.

Comment: Amazing! Evidently I should have taken a step back and gone back to the beginning, rather than persisting with an impractical method!